# php excel export text broken new line

Tags: php, excel

I have array data set in column row and export excel but if long text added then line broken.
Can you please suggest how to long text wrap?

```
    $heading = false;
    if(!empty($records)) {
      foreach($records as $row) {
        if(!$heading) {
          // display field/column names as a first row
          echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
          $heading = true;
        }   
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
```

- use [Chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) to return [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) Code [13](http://www.asciitable.com/):

  `echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . chr(13);`
- or use [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

  `echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . PHP_EOL;`

---

### Edit:

Line breaks will only show in Excel for cells that have "Wor Wrap" enabled.

In your output Excel file:

- **highlight** the data that was output by PHP
- **right-click** on the highlighted cell(s)
- choose **Format Cells**
- go to **Alignment** tab

check box **Word Wrap**.

If that fixes the issue then your data is (correctly) breaking the line, but it's just Excel's word-wrap default that's preventing the line breaks.  You can set it programmatically but it would need a different approach in writing to the file.  An easier solution is setup the formatting (including Word Wrap) in the file prior to writing to it, like a template.